# buddypress edit profile

Tags: buddypress, profiles

I have installed buddypress, I don't see any errors or success message when a person updates their profile details.

Also for some reason it only seems to update admins details, a normal user/subscriber, cannot update its on profile.

has anyone come across this? help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use `$bp->template_message` this was a bit tricky but then I had to go to bp-xprofile-screens.php just under line 77 I added `unset($is_required[1]);` to remove the username update, (as this does not need changing) :)

hope someone else, may find this useful.